# Grunt-karma aborted due to warnings

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner

I'm getting "Aborted due to warnings" error when running grunt in --verbose mode.

```
ar@Woody:~/www/mysite-frontend-dev$ grunt build:debug

...

Registering "grunt-karma" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/ar/www/mysite-frontend-dev/node_modules/grunt-karma/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/ar/www/mysite-frontend-dev/node_modules/grunt-karma/package.json...OK Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Is there a way to get more detailed output? This warning message doesn't say much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with grunt-concurrent and Debian "squeeze". Updating to the latest (0.4.1) grunt-concurrent resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can pass a command-line flag like `$ grunt build:debug --verbose` or `$ grunt build:debug --stack` to see more details